# awk to print lines containing lower values in two csv files

Tags: shell, unix, awk

file1.csv

```
1104,2020-05-04 00:00:00,ABC 
1911,2020-05-05 00:00:00,XYZ 
1298,2020-05-06 00:00:00,PQR 
1197,2020-05-06 00:00:00,XYZ 
1086,2020-05-07 00:00:00,PQR 
976,2020-05-07 00:00:00,ABC 
1546,2020-05-08 00:00:00,XYZ 
1695,2020-05-11 00:00:00,ABC 
2046,2020-05-12 00:00:00,XYZ 
1875,2020-05-13 00:00:00,ABC
```

file2.csv

```
1104,2020-05-04 00:00:00,ABC 
1921,2020-05-05 00:00:00,XYZ 
1298,2020-05-06 00:00:00,PQR 
1197,2020-05-06 00:00:00,XYZ 
187,2020-05-07 00:00:00,PQR 
976,2020-05-07 00:00:00,ABC 
1546,2020-05-08 00:00:00,XYZ 
695,2020-05-11 00:00:00,ABC 
2047,2020-05-12 00:00:00,XYZ 
1875,2020-05-13 00:00:00,ABC
```

AWK should compare all the three fields.2nd and 3rd field should be matched between file1 and fil2 and it willprint only those line where first field in file 1 > file2

In the above example it should print -

```
187,2020-05-07 00:00:00,PQR
695,2020-05-11 00:00:00,ABC
```

---

Comment: 2nd and 3rd field will always match or the lines should be printed only when these fields match?

Comment: Please share what have you tried so far ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk -F, 'NR==FNR{a[$2,$3]=$1; next} a[$2,$3]>$1' file1 file2
```

Comment: Can you please give some highlights on the command. I can understand only its comparing based on an a rray